Does a Poincaré inequality for a Markov process $X_t$ with invariant measure $μ$ infer a convergence rate of $\frac1t\int_0^tf(X_s){\rm d}s$ to $μf$?
Let $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a time-homogeneous shift-ergodic Markov process with transition semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ and invariant measure $\mu$. One implication of a Poincaré inequality is a $L^2$-contractivity $$\operatorname{Var}_\mu\left[\kappa_tf\right]\le e^{-2\lambda t}\operatorname{Var}_\mu[f]\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag1$$ for all $f\in L^2(\mu)$ for some $\lambda>0$. I see that we get an exponential convergence rate of $\kappa_tf$ to $\mu f$ in $L^2(\mu)$ as $t\to\infty$ for all $f\in L^2(\mu)$.
But can we also derive a convergence rate for the ergodic average $$A_tf:=\frac1t\int_0^tf(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for }t>0$$ to $\mu f$ as $t\to\infty$ for $f\in L^2(\mu)$? Intuitively, this should be possible.
For this, let $\operatorname P_x$ denote the measure wrt which $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is started at $x$. I guess the corresponding convergence would then hold in $L^2(\operatorname P_\mu)$, where $\operatorname P_\mu:=\int\mu({\rm d}x)\operatorname P_x$. But then I would also wonder of what practical use this convergence rate would be (since considerations wrt $\operatorname P_\mu$ mean that the process is started at $\mu$, which is clearly unrealistic in practice).
